# How to request again if image download failed using glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm try to download multiple images from server using the **Glide**

here is code

```
   for (String url : list) {
        RequestOptions requestOptions = RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);

        Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(url).addListener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                Log.e("ProgressCheck", "onResourceReady: " + progress);

                return false;
            }
        })
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .submit();
    }
```

Code run perfectly but when the downloading image failed (any reason wifi disconnected or server not responding.etc) how to send the same request again??

or is there the better way download multiple images using **Glide**

Comment: onLoadFailed() Could help?

Comment: not any onResourceFailed() callback method is there..

Comment: onLoadFailed()?

Comment: @VirRajpurohit ok but how to send the request again..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make a separate method of loading image via glide.

Here is the pseudo code

```
private void loadImage(String URL){
// Your Glide code
//Inside onLoadFailed call loadImage() again.
//For number of attempts you can maintain one int and increment that on every attempt.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If [error](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/placeholders.html#error) or [fallback](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/placeholders.html#fallback) strategies are not useful to you, then in 4.3.0 version you can starting a new request on failure:

```
Glide.with(fragment)
  .load(url)
  .error(
      Glide.with(fragment)
        .load(url))
        .into(imageView);
```

Learn more at https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/options.html#starting-a-new-request-on-failure

Comment: what happen when the `fallbackUrl` request failed?

Comment: @code4rox Did you read the link that you download on the fallback?

Fallback Drawables are shown when requested url / model is null. The primary purpose of Fallback Drawables is to allow users to indicate whether or not it is expected. For example, a null profile url may indicate that the user has not set a profile photo and that a default should be used. However, null may also indicate that meta-data is invalid or could not be retrieved. By default Glide treats null urls / models as errors, so users who expect null should set to fallback Drawable.

Comment: Strategies shown as those of @Vir Rajpurohit are unnecessary.
If you’re loading images from urls, Glide can automatically help you deal with flaky network connections by monitoring users’ connectivity status and restarting failed requests when users are reconnected. If Glide detects that your application has the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, Glide will automatically monitor connectivity status and no further changes are needed. Again, based on official documentation XD

Comment: About Connectivity Monitoring, for cases, you need to swipe to reload your URL when the Internet is restored: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html#connectivity-monitoring